# Restricting a set of predictions to a range of values of non-negative numbers

Tags: r, forecasting, prediction, prediction-interval

I am not even sure how to even phrase this question so if anyone could help that would be great.

I am analyzing facebook activity and I wish to predict a particular activity (comments, for instance). Doing this with R, and using the package 'forecast' my prediction for the future periods with 80 and 95% yield lower boundaries of negative numbers - this can't be. The minimum possible comments that any activity could have is 0. What can I do to restrict this with a valid statistical background instead of running some code to limit these values?

EDIT:

Here is a MRE, with data that very closely resembles the parameters of the data I am working with (which unfortunately I can't share), but in reality, anything that has a sd larger than a mean would yield similar results:

```
 library(forecast)
 TEST <- rnorm(150,mean=87,sd=140)
 # change negatives to 0
 TEST[TEST < 0] <- 0
 #It's crucial that the sd is larger than the mean, if not, repeat first commands
 mean(TEST)
 sd(TEST)
 arima.TEST <- arima(TEST, order = c(1,0,0))
 forecast.Arima(arima.TEST, h =12)
 #Lo 80 and Lo 95 are predicted in the negatives
```

Comment: Can you add some R code so we can have a closer look?

Comment: @KenanF.Deen I added some code in R that you could run. Bear in mind after the replacements, the sd needs to be larger to the mean in order to replicate my problem.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you want to avoid the negative numbers from your random number generation. Instead of convert the negative values to 0, I only would change the negative to positive sign using the absolute function of R as follow:

```
 TEST <- abs(rnorm(150,mean=87,sd=140))
```